# Simple 3D Collision guide please

Tags: xna-4.0

Hello im trying to do collision detection for 3D but only half of it works. Could someone give me a simple guide on how to create rectangle collision detection please? And if possible a guide what only detects the model collision guide

Answer (score 0):

Its wonderful to know that you are starting with XNA 3D.

Here is wonderful series to getting started with XNA 2D and [3D](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series1.php).

This is the best resource out there, I have used. It will clear every fundamental of 3D including terrain, polygon and collision.

Have a look at this, and please let me know if any further details are required.

Answer (score 0):

The simplist way is to use Bounding Boxes and the Intersects method.
i.e
Set the position of the bounding box to the centre position of the object
test whether the box intersects with another:

```
BoundingBox box1 = new BoundingBox(); 
BoundingBox box2 = new BoundingBox(); 

if (box1.Intersects(box2))
{
// do stuff
}
```

note the above initialisation of the bounding boxes wont work, im aware that you need to add some parameters, but i thought id show just for example.

Also you want the if function in your update loop, to constantly check for collision.
But please also note, that this is not the most efficient way, as a game with 1 million objects and your program is checking for collision between all of them at the same time will not work.